# Pandas: promedio columna dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Necesito sacar el promedio de la siguiente columna de nombre Tiempo1.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from statistics import mean

df0 = pd.read_csv('Datos.txt', header=0, delim_whitespace=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df0.shape[0]+1)

df0['Tiempo1'] = df0['Tiempo1'].replace('NaN','0.00')

print(mean(df0['Tiempo1']))
```

Y mi DataFrame es el siguiente:

```
 Fecha          Tiempo1           Tiempo2            Tiempo3            Tiempo4            Tiempo5          
 2007-01-01       NaN              12.32              13.95              15.35              16.45                             
 2007-01-02       NaN              12.58              14.08              15.32              16.37                         46.98       
 2007-01-03       10.57              12.50              14.15              15.47              16.45              3.72              NaN                NaN                NaN       
 2007-01-04       9.97              12.47              14.17              15.45              16.45                    
 2007-01-05       NaN              12.50              14.13              15.42              16.45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usaré el siguiente dataframe de ejemplo:

```
   Numbers_One  Numbers_Two
0        10.05        11.04
1         5.23        15.00
2         2.22         4.65
3          NaN          NaN
```

- En lugar de usar un replace, puedes usar el método fillna pasando de parámetro 0. Pandas posee este método para hacerte un replace de los valores NaN.
- mean es un método de la instancia, entonces tienes que llamarlo a partir de la columna seleccionada del dataframe.

**Código**

```
import pandas as pd

# Creamos una lista con datos:
data = [[10.05, 11.04], [5.23, 15], [2.22, 4.65], [None, None]]

# Creamos un dataframe de ejemplo a partir de los datos y le colocamos nombre a las columnas:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Numbers_One', 'Numbers_Two'])

# Llenamos los valores desconocidos con 0
df['Numbers_One'] = df['Numbers_One'].fillna(0)

# Imprimimos la media de la columna
print(df['Numbers_One'].mean())
```

**Resultado:**

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
4.375
```

**EDITO**

Como bien indica @Patricio, esto puede afectar a la media dependiendo de lo que necesites. Si hacemos un fillna(0), estamos llenando los campos con valores desconocidos con 0, por lo qué tendremos los siguientes números en la primera columna:

```
10.05
5.23
2.22
0
```

Para sacar la media, se estaría diviediendo entre 4, ya que el 0 formaría parte de los números de la columna.

Si sacamos la media obviando los valores que no estén definidos, estos no formarían parte de los números de la media, por lo qué serían solamente 3 los de la primera columna:

```
10.05
5.23
2.22
```

De esta forma para extraer la media, se estarían usando 3 números sin incluir los campos sin valor.

**Código**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[10.05, 11.04], [5.23, 15], [2.22, 4.65], [None, None]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Numbers_One', 'Numbers_Two'])

print(df['Numbers_One'].mean(skipna = True))
```

**Resultado:**

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
5.833333333333333
```

Esto depende de si necesitas incluir los campos sin valores asignados como parte de los valores para calcular la media o no.

[Más información de fillna() - Llenar valores desconocidos](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

[Más información sobre el método mean() - Media](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Comment: Cuidado con el `fillna(0)` ya que esto incide en el calculo de la media, tal vez sea más lógico usar `skipna = TRUE` para ignorar estos valores.

Comment: Buen punto, Patricio. Efectivamente. En un dataframe con muchos datos podría afectar más. Es una buena opción pasarle al método mean un skipna = True. Y aún así, no haía falta hacer un fillna, se podría omitir esa línea del código ya que internamente mean lo hace por defecto.

Comment: Un ejemplo con skipna = True

Comment: ¿Por que puede afectar el resultado del promedio?

Comment: Porque cada valor que sea 0 se está sumando 1 para sacar la media. Edito la pregunta y contesto esa parte.

Comment: Lo he añadido en la edición del código en el apartado donde hago un print. Sería True en lugar de TRUE aunque por defecto es lo que hace el método mean().